# Querying Data in a Column Referring to a Specific Entry

Tags: microsoft-access, vb.net

I have made an Access database which basically looks like this:

```
| Username | Password | EmployeeName   |

| admin    | admin    | Arnav Varshney |

| guest    | guest    | Test1          |
```

I have used the data in a Login Form that displays a message box after login is successful:

```
Dim text As String = "Login Successful! Welcome Back "
MessageBox.Show(text & 'EmployeeName', "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
```

What I am not able to understand is how to get the `EmployeeName` data that corresponds to the entered `Username` from the Access database, and display it in the `MessageBox`?

Comment: How exactly user enters credentials? how do you check it?

Comment: The user is not entering any credentials. The program is made such that it  returns the name of the Employee from the database. @MátéJuhász

Comment: "data that corresponds to the entered Username" - so is it entered or not? Could you please screen some screenshots to help us understanding your issue?